# Enviar peticiones al servidor en formato JSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Este es el script que se creo para generar las peticiones al servidor.
Mi duda es, si se pueden enviar las peticiones en formato json y recibir la respuesta de la misma manera.

Este es el código del script.

```
package com.paradox.house.other

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Intent
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.util.Log
import com.paradox.house.*
import com.paradox.house.model.RegistroPaciente
import khttp.responses.Response
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync
import org.jetbrains.anko.uiThread
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject
import khttp.delete as httpDelete

object Services {

  val rutaBASEServidor = Variables.url_servicios

  fun registrarPaciente(paciente: RegistroPaciente, context: Application, activity: Activity) {
        var success = false;
        var error_respuesta = ""
        doAsync {
            val response: Response = khttp.post(
                    url = rutaBASEServidor + "paciente/registrar",
                    data = mapOf("nombre" to paciente.nombre, "apellidos" to paciente.apellidos,
                            "curp" to paciente.curp, "sexo" to paciente.sexo, "edad" to paciente.edad,
                            "domicilio" to paciente.domicilio, "ocupacion" to paciente.ocupacion,
                            "peso" to paciente.peso, "embarazada" to paciente.embarazada,
                            "unidadMedica" to paciente.unidadMedica, "diagnostico" to paciente.diagnostico,
                            "fechaDiagnostico" to paciente.fechaDiagnostico,
                            "noSeguroPopular" to paciente.noSeguroPopular,
                            "jurisdiccion" to paciente.jurisdiccion, "infeccion" to paciente.infeccion,
                            "deteccion" to paciente.deteccion, "clasificacion" to paciente.clasificacion,
                            "confirmacion" to paciente.confirmacion, "lote" to paciente.lote,
                            "esquema" to paciente.esquema, "causaTermino" to paciente.causaTermino,
                            "idLocalidad" to paciente.idLocalidad, "idMedico" to paciente.idMedico)
            )
            val respuesta:JSONObject = response.jsonObject
            val mensaje = respuesta.get("success") as Boolean
            val idPaciente = respuesta.get("idPaciente") as Int

            success = mensaje;

            uiThread {
                if(success) {
                    val intent = Intent(context, RegistrarVisitaActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    intent.putExtra("idPaciente", idPaciente.toString())
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                    activity.finish()
                } else {
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    builder.setTitle("Error al registrar paciente")
                    builder.setMessage("El paciente ya se encuentra registrado")
                    val dialog:AlertDialog = builder.create()
                    dialog.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun cerrarSesion(context: Application, activity: Activity){
        val sharedPreferences =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.applicationContext)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString("username", "")
        editor.putString("password", "")
        editor.commit()
        val intent = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)
        activity.finish()
    }

    fun ingresar(email: String, password: String, context: Application, activity: Activity) {
        var apellido_medico:String
        var nombre_medico:String
        var nombreDoctor = ""
        var idMedico = 0
        var success = false
        var error_respuesta = ""
            doAsync {
                val response: Response = khttp.post(
                        url = rutaBASEServidor + "login",
                        data = mapOf("usuario" to email.toString(), "password" to password.toString()))
                val respuesta: JSONObject = response.jsonObject
                Log.d("Respuesta", respuesta.toString())
                val mensaje = respuesta.get("success") as Boolean
                var admin = 0
                var usuario = ""
                if (mensaje) {
                    admin = respuesta.get("admin") as Int
                    if (admin == 0) {
                        apellido_medico = respuesta.get("medico_apellidos") as String
                        nombre_medico = respuesta.get("medico_nombre") as String
                        nombreDoctor = nombre_medico + " " + apellido_medico
                        idMedico = respuesta.get("idMedico") as Int
                    }
                    usuario = respuesta.get("username") as String
                    success = mensaje
                    val sharedPreferences =
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.applicationContext)
                    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                    editor.putString("username", email)
                    editor.putString("password", password)
                    editor.putInt("idMedico", idMedico)
                    editor.commit()
                } else {
                    error_respuesta = respuesta.get("error") as String
                }
                uiThread {
                    if (success) {
                        if (admin == 1) {
                            val intent = Intent(context, PrincipalAdminActivity::class.java)
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            intent.putExtra("usuario_admin", usuario)
                            context.startActivity(intent)
                            activity.finish()
                        } else {
                            val intent = Intent(context, PrincipalMedicoActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra("nombre_doctor", nombreDoctor)
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            context.startActivity(intent)
                            activity.finish()
                        }
                    } else {
                        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        builder.setTitle("Error al iniciar sesión")
                        builder.setMessage(error_respuesta)
                        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                        dialog.show()
                    }
                }
            }

            }

    fun ingresar_inicio(email: String, password: String, context: Application, activity: Activity) {
        var apellido_medico:String
        var nombre_medico:String
        var nombreDoctor = ""
        var idMedico = 0
        var success = false
        var error_respuesta = ""
        doAsync {
            val response: Response = khttp.post(
                    url = rutaBASEServidor + "login",
                    json = mapOf("usuario" to email.toString(), "password" to password.toString()))
            val respuesta: JSONObject = response.jsonObject
            Log.d("Respuesta",respuesta.toString())
            val mensaje = respuesta.get("success") as Boolean
            var usuario= ""
            var admin = 0
            if(mensaje) {
                admin = respuesta.get("admin") as Int
                if(admin == 0){
                    apellido_medico = respuesta.get("medico_apellidos") as String
                    nombre_medico = respuesta.get("medico_nombre") as String
                    nombreDoctor = nombre_medico + " " +apellido_medico
                    idMedico = respuesta.get("idMedico") as Int
                }
                usuario = respuesta.get("username") as String
                success = mensaje
                val sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.applicationContext)
                val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                editor.putString("username", email)
                editor.putString("password", password)
                editor.putInt("idMedico",idMedico)
                editor.commit()
            }else{
                error_respuesta = respuesta.get("error") as String
            }
            uiThread {
                if (success) {
                    if(admin == 1){
                        val intent = Intent(context, PrincipalAdminActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        intent.putExtra("usuario_admin",usuario)
                        context.startActivity(intent)
                        activity.finish()
                    }else{
                        val intent = Intent(context, PrincipalMedicoActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("nombre_doctor",nombreDoctor)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        context.startActivity(intent)
                        activity.finish()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun registrarMedico(nombre: String, apellidos: String, unidadMedica: String,
                        correoElectronico: String, idMunicipio: String, password: String,
                        context: Application, activity: Activity) {
        var success = false
        var error_respuesta = ""
        doAsync {
            val response: Response = khttp.post(
                    url = rutaBASEServidor + "medico/registro",
                    data = mapOf("nombre" to nombre, "apellidos" to apellidos, "unidadMedica"
                    to unidadMedica, "correoElectronico" to correoElectronico,
                            "idMunicipio" to idMunicipio, "password" to password))
            val respuesta: JSONObject = response.jsonObject
            val mensaje = respuesta.get("success") as Boolean
            if(mensaje) {
                success = mensaje

                val sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.applicationContext)
                val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                editor.putString("username", correoElectronico)
                editor.putString("password", password)
                editor.commit()

            }
            uiThread {
                if (success) {
                    var nombreDoctor = nombre + " " + apellidos
                    val intent = Intent(context, PrincipalMedicoActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    intent.putExtra("nombre_doctor",nombreDoctor)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                    activity.finish()
                } else {
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    builder.setTitle("Error al registrarse")
                    builder.setMessage(error_respuesta)
                    val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                    dialog.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getPacientes( context: Application,
                      activity: Activity){
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.applicationContext)
        val idMedico = sharedPreferences.getInt("idMedico", 0)
        Log.d("idMedico",idMedico.toString())

        doAsync {
            val response: Response = khttp.post(
                    url = rutaBASEServidor + "paciente/get",
                    data = mapOf("idMedico" to idMedico))
            val respuesta: JSONArray = response.jsonArray
            Log.d("respuesta",respuesta.toString())
        uiThread {

        }
        }

        }

    fun registrarTratamiento(fecha: String, peso: String, medicamento: String, renuente: String,
                             reingreso: String, reaccionesAdversas: String, idPaciente: String,
                             context: Application, activity: Activity) {
        var success = false
        var error_respuesta = ""

        doAsync {
            val response: Response = khttp.post(
                    url = rutaBASEServidor + "tratamiento/registrar",
                    data = mapOf("fecha" to fecha, "peso" to peso, "medicamento" to medicamento,
                            "renuente" to renuente, "reingreso" to reingreso,
                            "reaccionesAdversas" to reaccionesAdversas, "idPaciente" to idPaciente))
            val respuesta: JSONObject = response.jsonObject
            val mensaje = respuesta.get("success") as Boolean
            if (mensaje) {
                success = mensaje
            }
            uiThread {
                if (success) {
                    val intent = Intent(context, VerInformacionPaciente::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("idPaciente", idPaciente)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                    activity.finish()
                } else {
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    builder.setTitle("Error al registrar tratamiento")
                    builder.setMessage(error_respuesta)
                    val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                    dialog.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun actualizarCausaTermino(idPaciente: String, causaTermino: String, context: Application,
                               activity: Activity) {
        var success = false
        var error_respuesta = ""
        doAsync {
            val response: Response = khttp.post(
                    url = rutaBASEServidor + "paciente/actualizar",
                    data = mapOf("idPaciente" to idPaciente, "causaTermino" to causaTermino))
            val respuesta: JSONObject = response.jsonObject
            val mensaje = respuesta.get("success") as Boolean
            if(mensaje) {
                success = mensaje
            }
            uiThread {
                if (!success) {
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    builder.setTitle("Error al actualizar causa término")
                    builder.setMessage(error_respuesta)
                    val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                    dialog.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el codigo como text en vez de una imagen. Es mucho mas facil ayudarte de esta manera. =)

Comment: @cavpollo Ya lo hice, pero no sé si esa sea la mejor manera.

Comment: Si asi esta bien. =) Ahora una duda. Tu pregunta es un poco ambigua. Si es posible enviar y recibir peticiones JSON, pero cual es tu problema? No funciona? Tienes algun error?

Comment: @cavpollo el código funciona bien, ya lo he probado y manda sin problemas las peticiones al servidor. Mi problema ahora es que necesito mandar las peticiones al servidor en formato json, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asi como [menciona la documentacion](https://khttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#more-complicated-post-requests), para enviar una request con KHTTP, tomando como ejemplo tu segundo Post, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
val payload = mapOf("usuario" to email.toString(), "password" to password.toString()))
val response: Response = khttp.post(
                    url = rutaBASEServidor + "login",
                    data = data=JSONObject(payload))
val respuesta: JSONObject = response.jsonObject
Log.d("Respuesta", respuesta.toString())
```